# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it - client side

Tags: c#, web-services, web-application-firewall

As a title suggests, I have encountered an error while trying to connect to the service server.

There is quite a resource base on the said error, but most of them assume some level of control over the server. In this case, I (and a team I am part of) am supplying the service itself to a customer, but have no control over the server administration whatsoever.

The service was written so that when I submit a request to address `_someIP_:8080/api/resource.json`, I should get a resource for the date specified in the request for a debug and support reasons.

I have built a simple C# client that accepts my input for a date, gathers the resource and parses it into a file.

It used to work until recently when I started to encounter the problem. The API has not changed, but the physical location of the server has `(and other administrative changes in the server may or may not have happened, I have no control over these)`.

I suppose server admins blocked ports by a firewall, or that it happened by accident during the relocation of the server, but I cannot be sure.

Can you see other reasons why would a problem like this would happen that I might have overlooked? 
And, is there any reasonable way, how to get to the resources needed from my side, or do I have to contact server admins and ask them to release ports?

Comment: Thats what any internal network team can help you with - as well as any hosting network team.  theres often firewalls included even perhaps the new servers OS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to contact the server administrators. Either there is a firewall blocking the connection or the process that is hosting the service is not listening on that port. This may be because it is not running at all or because it is listening on a different port.

I don't think there is something that you could do in order to access the server.

Answer (score 1):

This error is intentionally vague, as it's not considered the client machine's business why the connection was refused (as this can expose unauthorized business information).   It sounds like someone screwed up the migration when machines were physically moved. You need to contact server administration.